# Comparation doesnt work for certain values

Tags: java

Why does the code below:

```
List<Integer> elts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
elts.add(129);
elts.add(129);
System.out.println(elts.get(0) == elts.get(1));
```

returns (prints) `false`?

but it works for some other values (i.e if i replace 129 by 100/120/..etc). In fa

Comment: nothing wrong, what do you expet?

Comment: its a typo it was supposed to be == not !=, i changed it. It prints false even though 129==129??

Comment: Use `.equals` to compare objects (which Integers are). It works with `==` up to 128 due to the Integer cache

Comment: I see, thanks alot!